# In Azure How do I set the custom URL as default

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service

On my Azure webapp http://mortgagemiserblog.azurewebsites.net/ which is a WordPress site I want the default url to be http://www.mortgagemiser.com.au/ but when I go to http://www.mortgagemiser.com.au/ it resets the URL to http://mortgagemiserblog.azurewebsites.net/

Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: did you already check the official documentation for this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain

Answer (score 2):

Turns out to be a Wordpress setting under Settings General.